# Data lost after attempting to reinstall Ubuntu without losing data present on home folder

Tags: system-installation

Recently I had an issue with my Ubuntu 16.04, it was showing `/etc/mapper/cryptswap1` not present or not found,even it doesn't allowed me enter into ttyprompt also. So I booted my PC by pendrive with Ubuntu 16.04 on it.

While installing I was offered a choice to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 so that all the music, home, pictures and all personal files will be kept and only systemwide settings will be changed. So I chose that option and continued my installation, but when I restarted my PC all my old data had been lost. I can't find my data on home, whether the data is preserved or not I don't know, but I don't understand why does the installation give me that option. Is my data is still present on my PC, if so please tell me how can I retrieve my data.

Comment: @karel The suggested duplicate does not seem to provide a solution to the user's problem.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the old data is preserved in the old `/home/(username)` folder, while Ubuntu created a new home folder to ensure that settings still in the old `/home/(username)` won't conflict with the new installation.  You should be able to use a file browser (such as dolphin) to browse one level up from your user home folder, and find the other folder there, with your old data safe inside.

Comment: I've tried to find my old home on my filesystem,but i didn't find anywhere.